# Performance when using encrypted external drive on raspi 3b+

Tags: disk-encryption, luks, raspberry-pi, performance

I read [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/42100/performance-with-an-encrypted-disk) that the speed for an encrypted external drive on the pi is about 3MB/s. Is there a way to increase this by using a different cipher for dm-crypt/luks or tweak it in some other way?

Comment: Welcome! This site is for discussing the protection of assets from threats and vulnerabilities. Optimizing the performance of some (encryption) software for your Raspberry Pi has security aspects, but your main goal is to make the encryption faster. I think this question fits better on another stackexchange site, so I have voted to move the question to SuperUser. (No action is required from your side.)

Comment: you could always use a drive that has its own built in encryption